# DBUtils downloading files but files not present locally

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-connect

I'm trying to use `DBUtils` from `pyspark.dbutils` outside databricks, it shows me no warning or error when copying files locally, but files are not present in target folder.

I can check if the file exists on DBFS with `dbutils.fs.ls`, and file do exist.

My pyspark session is configured with `databricks-connect` and I can do SQL with it.

This is how I configure `databricks-connect` to connect to my cluster:

```
DATABRICKS_ADDRESS="https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.azuredatabricks.net/"
DATABRICKS_API_TOKEN="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
DATABRICKS_CLUSTER_ID="0000-0000-0000"
DATABRICKS_ORG_ID="0000000000000"
DATABRICKS_PORT="0000"
stdin_list = [DATABRICKS_ADDRESS, DATABRICKS_API_TOKEN, DATABRICKS_CLUSTER_ID, DATABRICKS_ORG_ID, DATABRICKS_PORT]
stdin_string = '\n'.join(stdin_list)
echo = subprocess.Popen((['echo', '-e', stdin_string]), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = subprocess.check_output(('databricks-connect', 'configure'), stdin=echo.stdout)
```

Then I get the SparkSession from databricks cluster (if running; else waiting to wake up)

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
```

Now I can configure DBUtils and manipulate files on DBFS:

```
from pyspark.dbutils import DBUtils
dbutils = DBUtils(spark)
dbutils.fs.cp("dbfs:/data/project/my_file.model", "/mnt/c/Users/my_user/project/my_file.model")


22/09/12 12:00:45 WARN SparkServiceRPCClient: Large server response (46597327 bytes compressed)
22/09/12 12:00:45 WARN SparkServiceRPCClient: Large server response (49063049 bytes total)
22/09/12 12:00:45 WARN DBFS: DBFS open on dbfs:/data/project/my_file.model took 6857 ms
22/09/12 12:00:52 WARN DBFS: DBFS create on /mnt/c/Users/my_user/project/my_file.model took 6758 ms
```

But my folder at `/mnt/c/Users/my_user/project/`, there is no file `my_file.model`.

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/mnt/c/Users/my_user/project/my_file.model'
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I was moving the data inside the DBFS. So the behaviour is normal. I thought the tool was made to interract local/remote files.

What I needed is to use `DBFS CLI` or the [internal pyspark fonctions](https://gist.github.com/idiomer/ef70cd0ac6bf0326599db2286f41a974). (works with any distributed file system, DBFS/HDFS)

If links dies, you can look up for `JVM gateway` or `copyToLocalFile pyspark`

Comment: have you tried with specifying the local path as `file:/....` ?